# Conditional Where Clause in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to add a conditional `where` clause to a query depending on what model is asking for the associated `Comments`:

```
public List<Comments> GetCommentsByResource(string ResourceName, Guid ResourceID)
{
    var query = CommentsManager.GetQueryable();

    switch (ResourceName)
    {
        case "Bike":
            query.Where(x => x.BikeID == ResourceID);
            break;
        case "Skis":
            query.Where(x => x.SkiID == ResourceID);
            break;
        case "Helmet":
            query.Where(x => x.HelmetID == ResourceID);
            break;
        case "Scooter":
            query.Where(x => x.ScooterID == ResourceID);
            break;
    }

    return query.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedOn).ToList();
}
```

I can trace the execution and the switch statements are being correctly hit-- but when the query is executed, it isn't applying the `where` and the list returns all comments. What am I missing?

Comment: `Where` returns a new query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture the result of the `Where(...)` and store it in a *(new)* variable.

```
public List<Comments> GetCommentsByResource(string ResourceName, Guid ResourceID)
{
    var query = CommentsManager.GetQueryable();

    switch (ResourceName)
    {
        case "Bike":
            query = query.Where(x => x.BikeID == ResourceID);
        //  ^^^^^^^
            break;
        case "Skis":
            query = query.Where(x => x.SkiID == ResourceID);
            break;
        case "Helmet":
            query = query.Where(x => x.HelmetID == ResourceID);
            break;
        case "Scooter":
            query = query.Where(x => x.ScooterID == ResourceID);
            break;
    }

    return query.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedOn).ToList();
}
```

You need to check if the result type of the where matches the result type of `CommentsManager.GetQueryable();`. You might explicitly declare the type instead of `var query`.

Answer (score 1):

Just set your query to the value of the conditional statement

```
public List<Comments> GetCommentsByResource(string ResourceName, Guid ResourceID)
{
var query = CommentsManager.GetQueryable();

switch (ResourceName)
{
    case "Bike":
        query = query.Where(x => x.BikeID == ResourceID);
        break;
    case "Skis":
        query = query.Where(x => x.SkiID == ResourceID);
        break;
    case "Helmet":
        query = query.Where(x => x.HelmetID == ResourceID);
        break;
    case "Scooter":
        query = query.Where(x => x.ScooterID == ResourceID);
        break;
}

return query.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedOn).ToList();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The query have to be updated with the new condition, therefore query=query.Where(...) have to be used.

I also recommend you to use "if" instead of "switch" so that code is more extendable with the query with unlimited no. of conditions.

```
public List<Comments> GetCommentsByResource(int resourceNo, string resourceName)
{
    var query = CommentsManager.GetQueryable();

    if(resourceNo>-1)
       query = query.Where(x => x.ResourceID == resourceNo);
    if(resourceName=="A")
       query = query.Where(x => x.ResourceName == "A");
    .....

    return query.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedOn).ToList();
}
```